# Обёртка для изображений в записях Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, schema.org

Есть рабочий сайт на WP, есть уже добавленные записи с изображениями. Решил добавить microdata и сейчас стал перед проблемой, нужно все изображения в записях обернуть в 
`<p itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject"><img itemprop="url"></p>` 
и img добавить атрибут itemprop="url"

Как это можно сделать без добавления вручную? И есть ли способ, чтобы в дальнейшем все изображения в записях автоматически оборачивались в этот тег?

Comment: Ну скорее всего только js если не ручками. Хотя насколько я помню то не всем картинка нужно атрибут добавлять, а основной

Comment: а что должно быть в url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте хук `post_thumbnail_html`. Добавьте этот код в functions.php вашей темы.

```
function filter_post_thumbnail_html( $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr ) {
    $html = str_replace( '<img ', '<img itemprop="url" ', $html);
    $html = '<p itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">' . $html . '</p>';

    return $html;
}

add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'filter_post_thumbnail_html', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: ..а лучше в свой плагин :)

Comment: Но, подумав... наверное ещё лучше в шаблоне темы. Фильтр всё же доп нагрузка.

Comment: @SeVlad если вывод по всему сайту, с 15 разных шаблонов, то устанешь их все править.

Comment: @KAGGDesign может автор имел в виду полностью все картинки а не только миниатюры  ?

Comment: @Даниил а если картинка выводится не средствами WordPress (просто вставкой кода html в php), никакая автоматизация невозможна.

Comment: @KAGGDesign имеется в виду если картинка как медиафайл в контенте + миниатюра

Comment: @Даниил ну разве что такие изображения, выводимые как html, обрабатывать скриптом в браузере.

Comment: @Даниил "имеется в виду если картинка как медиафайл" - как выводится? Если через get_the_post_thumbnail(), то сработает.

Comment: если через the_content(); например.  Если например у человека стоит задача обернуть все картинки на сайте. То есть и миниатюры и те что в постах

Comment: @Даниил the_content() тоже можно фильтровать. Но вопрос разрастается до неопределенных размеров.  А если у него еще 33 плагина картинки выводят?

Comment: @KAGGDesign тоже верно. И в вопросе не уточнил.

Comment: Ну тогда можно (может даже и лучше) фильтр на `wp_insert_post` и тп :)

Comment: @SeVlad если у него уже 1000 постов на сайте, то не поможет.

Comment: Ну если простой функцией (в одноразовый плагинчик) обновить все посты, то поможет. Или же существующие обработать плагом поиска-замены с регулярками. Эт смотря какие реальные задачи. Вопрос как обычно оставляет большой простор для фантазий :)

Comment: @SeVlad и как обычно, никаких уточнений от автора, вся дискуссия между завсегдатаями SO )))

Comment: Sorry for late response :) Вообщем есть уже сотня записей и в каждой из них нужно обернуть ВСЕ картинки в этот тег <p> и добавить атрибут к <img>

Comment: @KAGG Design, добавил фильтр наподобие вашего, только для the_content. Есть ли возможность, чтобы сразу в бд поменяло?

Comment: Фильтрами в БД не залезть. Можно использовать, например, https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

> Как это можно сделать без добавления вручную?

Изменить вывод [шаблоне](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) темы. В [дочерней](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B), чтобы не потерять возможность обновления.