# Как изменить обертку у изображений в посте?

Tags: wordpress

Нужно изменить стандартную обертку при выводе изображений в посте. Изображения там оборачиваются в `<p></p>`

На нашел вариант удаления обертки:

```php
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_img_ptags_func');
function remove_img_ptags_func( $content ){
  return preg_replace('/<p>\s*((?:<a[^>]+>)?\s*<img[^>]+>\s*(?:<\/a>)?)\s*<\/p>/i', '\1', $content );
}
```

Пытался адаптировать под свои цели, но не выходит (в регулярках не силен):

```php
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_img_ptags_func');
function remove_img_ptags_func( $content ){
  $pattern = "/<p>\s*((?:<a[^>]+>)?\s*<img[^>]+>\s*(?:<\/a>)?)\s*<\/p>/i";
  $replacement = "/<div class='wrapper-img'>\s*((?:<a[^>]+>)?\s*<img[^>]+>\s*(?:<\/a>)?)\s*<\/p>/i";
  $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
  return $content;

}
```

Подскажите, есть ли возможность поменять обертку у изображений.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обёртка для изображений в записях Wordpress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743809/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%91%d1%80%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%85-wordpress)

Comment: Вам надо найти, где они оборачиваются в `<p>...</p>` и отменить тот фильтр.